# How to fade in background image?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, fadein

I want an image to pre-load and fade in when ready. I have the pre-loader working but can't get the fade effect.

What I tried:

1: CSS3 transitions - doesn't work for background images.

2: jQuery fadeIn - only works on HTML elements and not CSS background image. Trying to fade an element results in all elements within also fading.

jQuery:

```
$(bg).imagesLoaded({
    done: function($images){
        $('body').css('background-image', "url('" + $images[0].src + "')");
```

CSS:

```
body{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

I understand that there may not be a slick way of achieving this but I have seen it done here for example so there must be a way: http://movies.io/m/4I/en.

Comment: Does it have to be a background image? Is there any reason you can't just use the img element? You can do it with css transitions btw

Comment: You could create a separate element and affect the entire element, rather than putting a background image on the body.

Comment: That is the background image on the link you gave, so it must be another element that has a black background colour and it fades out once the image is loaded.

Comment: @alimac83 Well, in the example site background image is used so since it can be done I'd rather do it this way as opposed to adding extra elements in html. though if there's a nice solution with img without major trade offs then I will use that.

Comment: @Archer Exactly, see for div with classes teaser & darkable

Comment: @Archer so what you mean is that there is a black div that is just covering up the background image until it is loaded and then fades away?

Comment: @DominicM   ya, see my comment just over

Comment: Well the only downside of using css 3 transitions is that it won't be supported by older browsers - I'm not sure if that's an issue or not?

Comment: ok, how would I go about positioning such an element so that it is still behind content but obove background image? absolute positioning? Is there a better solution at all?

Comment: Fixed position with 100% width & height

Comment: @DominicM that's what it looks like to me, yeah.

Comment: @alimac83 not really an issue since I use ajax/jquery all over so old browsers woun't work anyway, that being said if I can support more browsers it#s better.

Comment: In that case, take a look here: http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/fading-button-background-images-with-css3-transitions/

Comment: I saw that before but now it seems like a good solution since older browsers will just default to the image appearing without a transition which isn't bad. Do you have a link for browser support? I am a little worried about smartphone/tablet support...

Comment: @alimac83 can you post this as an answer with an example of how the code should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a more elegant solution that did not require additional div elements.

What happens here is that when the image has finished loading background-image css will be added with jquery and the class that sets body color to white is faded away. Hope it's helpful to someone!

jQuery: (in the images loaded function)

```
$('body').css('background-image', "url('" + $images[0].src + "')");
$('#wrapper').removeClass("bgFade", 700);
```

CSS:

```
.bgFade{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the background image solution, then create the elements, set the background images on them, something like this:

```
background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');<br>
```

And then animate the individual elements using jQuery.

**Here is a fiddle for demonstration:**
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/6rXjs/3/embedded/result/

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can should do something like this

```
<div> <-- the block
    <div class="background">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

use position:absolute, to put .content over the .background div. And apple fadeIn to the .background. This is also used when you need an opaque background in div.

Comment: read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-center-position-absolute-div/) for centering absolutely positioned elements or use some javascript